# Lego Walkcycle Sliding Problem

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, bones, path

i have a problem. i want the lego-minifigure to walk without sliding. I tried it with a rootbone and a path but i always get sliding. i also tried offset- walking, but it did not work. what else can i do? i want to reuse the walkcycle for other animation.s i spent 3 days but can't make it work. i watched a lot of tutorials, but is is still not working. i need this animation, but i can't go on without a working walkcycle.

Comment: first you need to make sure that the walk cycle is correct, the feet must move in a linear speed along the X axis, otherwise it will inevitably slide when your character will move. You have several methods to do it, what have you tried? Then when you're good you need to synchronize the walk cycle speed with the speed of the character in the scene (along the curve for example)

Comment: thanks for the answer. here you can see my walkcycle. how can i set the speed linear on the xaxis? https://drive.google.com/open?id=17nnqLqvLiJYV9eHgm3UU2AyMgO5YWffQ

Comment: I will try to explain my method but it will take time   ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: simpler solution

So here is a method to make a non-sliding walk cycle. This is the *Dopsheet* part, once you have finished, when you'll move the character through the scene from point A to point B, you'll need to adjust the speed so that the walk doesn't slide, but it's another topic.

- Create a pose at frame 0, for example with left foot forward, keyframe, put your 3D cursor just in front of this foot:

[image]

- Copy the pose with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, go to frame 20, paste flip with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, move the whole armature until the left bone reach its former position behind the 3D cursor, keyframe everything:

[image]

- Put your 3D cursor in front of the right foot this time, go to frame 40, paste the first pose with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, move the whole armature until the right bone reach its former position behind the 3D cursor, keyframe everything:

[image]

- Select all your keyframes in the *Dope Sheet* and press T to *Interpolate > Linear*:

[image]

- Create all the intermediate keyframes (frame 10 and 30 in my example). This time don't copy the root bone position:

[image]

- Deactivate the root bone in the *Dope Sheet* so that your walk cycle will be still:

[image]

Now your walk cycle is ready to play, push it down into the *NLA*, repeat the strip, parent your armature to an empty, keyframe the empty in the 3D scene, synchronise the speed of the empty with the walk cycle so that the feet don't slip, or play with the strip *Playback Scale* value, etc...

Comment: thank you a lot for this, but i still can't make it work. i don't know what i am doing wrong. it is so frustraiting :(

Comment: please share your file (the armature only): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: also, what you show in your video is a still character, if you want to show the sliding you should make him move forward in the scene, from point A to B

Comment: i animated it by hand. that  is what it should look like, but i can't always animate it new so i need an other way. --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=11W-UaX8ojRxNxVXBVc2nE5RO4cu4Rwpi

Comment: i uploaded the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=04vpoxn9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/04vpoxn9/)

Comment: You've created an action called GEHEN. In the Dopesheet, on the left panel, we can see that you've created keyframes for the bones but also for the armature object itself (under Object Transforms). If you create a walk cycle, don't assign any LocRotScale keyframe to the object itself, only animate the bones. Also, don't animate the root bone for a walk cycle (except as I do). Then when you're glad with the bones animation, make the armature follow a path to make it move across the scene, or create a 2nd action that animates the armature from point A to B, then mix action 1 and 2 in the NLA.

Comment: i animated it now without the rootbone in the walkcycle, but still have sliding like you can see here --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xlMRKNnbs1qSNaxDfAwkPaeq6yLraefz

Comment: it can have 2 different reasons: either the initial walk cycle is not good, and you need to follow my method, or your walk cycle is good but its speed is not synchronized with the speed of the object in the scene, and you need to fix that

Comment: i have to give up then. not even fliping keyframes work -.-

Comment: to paste flip you need to select the bones then ctrl C then ctrl shift V, then insert a keyframe

Comment: yes but mirroring does not work. i stopped blender 1 year ago only because i can't make the walkcycle right. :D i just tried your version 3 times still not working.

Comment: because your bones need suffixes like _R and _L, otherwise Blender dan't mirror. Maybe follow some basic tutorials about rigging and walk cycles   ;)