# How do I create seamless walking animation?

Tags: animation

I am new to this particular website. While I have been teaching myself 3d art & animation for the entire time of Covid19 quarantine, I'm left with a small hiccup.

I downloaded a Mixamo character with a basic walk animation. And I was able to repeat the action within Blender2.8. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to continue the walk with an offset so that the character does not repeat the walk from its origin but rather continues along a seamless path. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will ink a video to show what I am describing. Thank you.

Blender Animation Video Link:
https://streamable.com/i5930c

Comment: here I explain how to make a walk cycle: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/lego-walkcycle-sliding-problem/159796#159796 ... but as your walk is moving forward what you could do is pushing you animation down into the NLA, repeat the strip several times, and at the beginning of each iteration, move the armature to the exact spot where it is supposed to begin. Please tell me if it's clear

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I somewhat know what you are referring to, however I don't think my character has a sliding problem with the walking. I just need the character to continue walking on a path without having to repeat the action of walking at frame 0.