# Help to convert root animation to in place animation

Tags: animation

I have a root animation and need to convert it to in place, if I disable the the Y movement curve in Y, the body keeps in place but the feet still going forward and I don’t know how to make them keep the motion while preserving their position related to the root. Not sure if this is possible or if is too advanced, here’s a gif showing the problem:

[image: Hip Y movement curve disabled, but the feet movement still going forward]

Does anybody knows what settings should be changed in order to make the feet movement happens in place?

Comment: you should make the root follow the feet at the exact same speed, then deactivate the root

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the original root movement was following the feet already. What I did was just unmark the root curve to make it stay in place. But with the feet I don't know how to make that happen cause their movement are more complex. Not sure if I understand what you meant here.

Comment: so maybe your armature is not correctly build, because it means that your feet are completely independant from the root, which should not be the case, their controler should be parented to the root

Comment: I unparented the feet from the root to make steps animation easier, cause if the're linked the feet keeps moving with the root (obviously), which makes a run forward animation harder to work with once I must correct the feet position frame by frame. But now, even if I parent the foot with the root (keep offset), the result is like this: https://imgur.com/a/gnrSWuI

Comment: if your goal is to make a still walk cycle animation, I've given a method here, I hope it helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/lego-walkcycle-sliding-problem/159796#159796

Comment: I'm afraid my scenario is more complex than it looks. My goal is to build a "partial root motion" to use in Unity. Firstly, I  build this animation with root motion in blender and extract the movement coordinates of the root in a txt using a script. Then I need to convert the exact same animation to in place in order to work with it in Unity. The coordinates extracted before will be used to create a movement curve in Unity. All of this work in an attempt to conciliate movement responsiveness, using code and movement precision, using that root motion coordinates in Unity.

Comment: But I'll take a look at that post, maybe there's something for me there...

Comment: well it gets a bit too complicated for me, maybe someone will be able to understand your needs   ;)