# Is there any root motion workflow that doesn't require feet adjustments on frame by frame basis?

Tags: animation, workflow

been searching for an hour or so, but wasn't able to find an specific answer about this problem. I need to make animations moving the character's root around for my game, so in place animations aren't a possibility. For now, I moved just the root bone (whole character) in straight line to ensure it has the speed movement I need in game, but now I need to start to add the actual feet movement to this animation movement. It happens that both feet follow the root movement (obviously), even when one of them should be planted. I did find some information pieces around the web, but nothing fixed this problem for me. I really need a best workflow for this, cause fixing the feet position on frame by frame basis seems to be a very bad, not to mention time consuming, way to do things.

I even considered unparent the feet from the root, but I'm positive this will cause problems in Unity as I need to use Humanoid rig there, which presupposes that the whole bone chain is connected to a single root.

I'm using Blender 2.8 and my rig was genereted by Makehuman, with the optimized for game engines option checked.

Does anynone knows a good workflow for this case? Maybe I missed something in my previous searches, cause this doesn't seems to be a big deal at all, it must have a better way to this..

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Have you seen the [Royal Skies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnqcxhOV-xQ) series on rigging Blender characters for Unity? The linked video looks like what you are asking about, the character's root seems to be moving with the character.

Comment: Thanks, but I already watched this videos, it wasn't what I meant. His animations are "in place" in the preview window in Unity, which means that the movement is being applied by code, probably. This is the kind of animation I want to do:
https://youtu.be/j7XZ3Q8JNfM?t=71

Comment: are you sure you need to move the root bone? If your goal is to make your character walk without any feet sliding, I gave a solution here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/lego-walkcycle-sliding-problem/159796#159796

Comment: Well, move the root around seems the right decision considering I need root motion on Unity. Also, I want to make sure that the character moves at certain speed. The method described yesterday worked for what I need so far. Do you think there's more to consider here? Does move root around may cause any issues that Im not aware of?

Comment: Use IK for the feet that are unparented to the root.  These IK targets exist only as controls (and you can, if you'd rather, even use an empty as the target instead of the bone.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a guy on Blender Artists gave a suggestion that worked in my first test. Create 2 auxiliary bones and link them on each foot using the copy transform modifier, this makes the feet follow these auxiliary bones instead of the root, overwriting the original parenting of the armature for the animations, while keeps the original parenting scheme in place for exporting.

If anyone need more details on this method, the complete answer can be checked at:

https://blenderartists.org/t/is-there-any-root-motion-workflow-that-doesnt-require-feet-adjustments-on-frame-by-frame-basis/1247260

Answer (score 0):

Use either Inverse Kinematics and dont parent those bones to the root, or use a secondary armature (or bones not parented) from which you will copy the rotation and location. Mark every bone that doesnt deform directly the mesh as those as no Deform, so those dont get exported.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the idea behind the **Root** bone.

Your body animation should be controlled by a body **Master** bone, which is usually around the center of mass - for example a **Master Hip** bone, which moves all deforming bones around.

You can leave the controller bones like IK and Pole target bones parented to the **Root** bone.

When you do your walk cycle animation you usually start keying the poses in place (like on a treadmill). Why? Because it is easier to observe your animation and not chasing the body around.

Once you are done with the "treadmill" walk cycle you can use the **Master Hip** bone to advance in space **one cycle** of your animation.

Once you are done with that and you would like to continue moving forward - you can make your animation cyclic and push (animate) the **Root** bone forward every time a cycle is complete.

**Basically the **Root** bone serves to reposition the looping animation in 3D space seamlessly.**

If you do more complex animations that do not require repetition you don't need to animate the **Root** bone at all.