# How to set the global position of a bone in an action (e.g. animation)?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am trying to create a walk animation. As I want to use it in a game later on, I started with moving the root bone forward. For the first half of the animation, I want to keep the controller bone in place, then in the second half move it forward. So the inverse kinematics I applied would move the leg, but leave the foot in place.

However, as I copied the starting keyframe of the foot and pasted it into the middle of the action, it didn't affect the foot at all - because the root bone moves and affects all childs, so the foot controller as well.

[image: screenshot out of the editor]
As you see here, the bone `shin.R.Control` has actually exactly the same keyframe at the start as in the middle. But it doesn't affect the actual position at all.

I did my own research, but I found only questions & solutions about python scripts.

Comment: it's hard to understand, are your trying to create a "treadmill" walk cycle or does your character move forward for real? For solution 1 you need to move your root bone forward but it will be deactivated later, for the second solution you don't need to move the root bone. First solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/lego-walkcycle-sliding-problem/159796#159796

Comment: I want the latter effect you described. For the latter solution, why wouldn't I need to move the root bone? If the root bone is not moved, the walk animation in game would always reset upon animation restart.

Comment: Just checked; the highest parent becomes the origin.

Comment: aah ok I was going to ask. So I suppose you make the armature, therefore the origin/root, move with some commands. So why should the root move within the actions? I try to understand, I hope an expert will answer

Comment: Maybe you should try the method I describe in the link except you don't disable the root at the end (so the character moves forward for real)

Comment: You're right, actually, I don't have any reason to move the root bone if the armature is parented anyway. I should have thinked more about this before asking this. Could you actually send this as an answer, "There is no need in moving the root bone if the armature is the parent at the end anyway. See this link for how to make a walk animation: <your link that you posted earlier>", so I can mark this as solved? Or how would I handle a question posted here with another underlying problem, actually? Deleting?

Comment: actually yes you should move it but try the method I link, if the root becomes the origin it means at the end it won't move. Leave your question as it is for the moment, give a test with my method, come back and tell if it works and I will answer with the necessary precisions

Comment: The root _does not_ become origin, but more the armature, which makes the whole root motion thing senseless. I'll try your link now

Comment: sure, but to make it easy to create the walk cycle you can indeed move the root and use the method I linked, once imported in the game engine, the root won't move if I understand correctly

Comment: Had a few other problems that were related to my bone structure, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: so did you use the linked method?