# How can I properly move a running character in space?

Tags: animation

I have a hard time understanding how to make sure my character's feet won't slip while running or just moving around.

I'm making a character running without run cycle, one step at a time. I would love to be able to lock his foot on the ground at every step so I could rearrange his body armature around that point for the next one. Like in real life might I say.

What I currently have is a character moving forward independently of his body movement, his feet slipping off and going through the floor.

I'm sure there's a simple way around this as it's a common problem. I guess I could do something with a Child of bone constraint as I've been able to make a character pick up and let go of something with it but I struggle with understanding how to apply that to the situation and researching my issue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: if you're moving your character without any run cycle, it should be easy to avoid feet slipping, not sure what's your problem, could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: I will get on that as soon as I can. Should I mention that I'm using Pose mode to pose my character but I'm using Object mode to move the character in space ? Maybe that's where  I've gone wrong.

Comment: yes, you need to choose, either make a walk cycle and move the armature forwards in Object mode, or move it forwards in Pose mode and in that case don't move it in Object mode

Comment: in the first case, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159782/lego-walkcycle-sliding-problem/159796#159796

Comment: Thanks a lot (as always), moonboots! I'll try it probably both ways.